# SQL Injection Help - PHP

Tags: sql-injection

I've created a simple table and php codes to inject it : here is my php codes :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test",$link);
$id = @$_GET["id"];
if($id != ""){
    mysql_query("delete from students where id=" .$id,$link);
}
?>
```

As id in link bar I intered :

```
1 ; drop table students ;
```

But it didn't work.
What is the problem ?
thanks

Comment: The search can do [magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Because mysql_query doesn't support this particular kind of injection

Comment: So how can I inject this ?

Comment: Just **don't** inject anything.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

So
drop table students;

never gonna be executed